# Traduction de « making out »

Tags: traduction, anglais, expressions

Je cherche une traduction du terme anglais « *making out* », « *to make out* », « *we made out* ». Ce terme, dans le contexte que je cherche, s'associe au fait d'embrasser quelqu'un longtemps, de même que de les toucher, etc. C'est une activité qui dure d'habitude plusieurs minutes, même quelques heures.

Je pensait à « s'embrasser », mais ça ne satisfait pas tous les critères. « On s'est embrassé » pourrait autant exprimer que deux personnes se sont embrassés pendant une ou deux secondes sans se toucher autrement.

Je ne crois pas qu'il y ait de mot pour ce que je cherche, mais on ne sait jamais, peut-être aurez vous quelque chose !

Comment: « s'associe au fait d'embrasser quelqu'un longtemps, de même que de les toucher, etc » Vraiment? J'ai toujours assumé que c'était simplement un synonyme de *to French kiss*...

Comment: @Circeus j'ai aussi assumé cela longtemps, mais ai tout récemment découvert la "vraie" signification. Voir [article de Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Making_out).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Mon dictionnaire propose « se peloter ».

Comment: Bien que cela me semble beaucoup plus vulgaire que son équivalent anglais, cela a beaucoup de sens. Merci!

Comment: En plus de me sembler beaucoup plus vulgaire que son équivalent anglais, ça me semble beaucoup plus vulgaire que ce que ça cherche à traduire, à moi. (À l'opposé, « se câliner », [plus bas](http://french.stackexchange.com/a/2402/1514).)

Comment: Que devient alors "let's make out" : « pelotons-nous » ? « On se pelote ? » Cette traduction me semble ne pas s'accorder avec l'usage commun de cette phrase en anglais.

Comment: Attention ! Au Québec, "se pelotter" est une façon excessivement vulgaire de dire "avoir une relation sexuelle". Mieux vaut éviter.

Comment: @AlexandreP.Levasseur Mais on prononce avec trois syllabes j'imagine et ça vient sans doute de _peloter avant la partie_; c'est encore l'influence de ce jeu de paume !

Comment: Je pense que c'est définitivement l'expression qui convient, et ca recouvre  à mon sens exactement les mêmes actions physiques que "make out". Ca n'a rien de plus ou moins vulgaire, on est peut-être moins habitués à l'utiliser par discrétion, préférant le "on s'est embrassé", pouvant sous-entendre "et autres attouchements..."

Answer (score 15):

Peut-être *se bécoter*? J'avoue que je suis influencé par la traduction de [la scène où Kevin s'échappe du Plaza](http://www.replikultes.net/films/fiches/454/maman_j_ai_encore_rate_l_avion_/repliks/#replik_13747) dans *Maman J'ai Raté l'Avion 2* (l'original emploie « smooching »).

Comment: J'étais curieux, [voici la scene en question, v.o.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VWxDmBocGrM). Puisqu'aucun autre contexte n'est donné, il est difficile pour moi de confirmer si c'est donc bien ce dont je parle, mais bonne suggestion!

Comment: La définition du dictionnaire renvoie à plein de petits baisers, mais personnellement j'ai plutôt tendance à l'interpréter de manière euphémique (probablement à cause du film: je n'ai jamais vu le mot employé ailleurs!).

Comment: @Circeus: [Brassens](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RYJmpsqJu-Y)?

Comment: @Stéphane Gimenez Ah, ben tu vois, je suis probablement trop jeune (né 1984) pour être familier avec cette chanson ^_^;;

Comment: Hmmm, on peut être né après ça et connaître quand même ;·)

Answer (score 12):

L'argot récent donne « se chopper », voir son verlan « pécho » dans un contexte très familier (mais pas spécialement vulgaire).

« Se peloter » peut convenir suivant le contexte mais sous-entend des attouchements plus que des baisers.

« Se bécoter » convient tout à fait mais peut sonner un peu daté suivant le contexte.

Toujours dans le registre familier, « se rouler des pelles » transmet bien l'idée.

« Se câliner » est moins usuel mais tout le monde comprendra.

Comment: +1 pour *se câliner*, notion d'affection, de tendresse qui peut s'appliquer tant aux relations amoureuses que filiales.

Comment: +1 pour tous les autres, *câliner* n'est pas une bonne traduction.

Comment: +1 pour la variété ; câliner n'est pas forcément bien traduit, mais selon les cas le registre de langue peut être plus important que le sens littéral, et les autres choix sont franchement familiers. Dans la plupart des argots étudiants que j'ai croisés, *chopper* n'était pas pronominal (au contraire, très transitif), et était essentiellement un synonyme de « *to French kiss* ».

Comment: Encore une fois, ce sont toutes des expressions seulement utilisables en France à l'exception de "becotter" qui a la même signification.

Answer (score 3):

Mon dictionnaire quant à lui me propose *s'emballer* (argot) --> *s'embrasser*.

Comment: Malheureusement *emballer* est unilatérale.

Answer (score 1):

*Flirter*, à mon avis ça le fait (dans le sens physique du terme).

Comment: *Flirter* c'est « faire la cour à quelqu’un » ou « entretenir des relations de coquetterie; badiner; faire la cour ». *Make out* implique une interaction physique, type bécoter/peloter.

Answer (score 1):

Je pense à "se découvrir" : avec des connotations intéressantes sur la durée et surtout le double sens de découvrir : connaître et dévêtir.

Answer (score 0):

Après de longues années à le voir et le lire, j'en déduis que c'est une action décrite avec seulement ce verbe et qui comprend les choses suivantes : embrasser, toucher (peloter), s'enlacer pour flirter physiquement sans aller dans les relations intimes.

Answer (score -3):

dans un registre commun -et dans la bouche d'un(e) collégien(ne) en général..- sortir avec quelqu'un, flirter est pas mal

Comment: Mais ce n'est pas ce que veut dire « making out ». C'est une activité spécifique avec contact prolongé.

Comment: c'est ce qui se disait quand j'étais au collège (comme cité plus haut, j'imagine que les petits mecs d'aujourd'hui disent qu'ils ont pé-cho...)

Comment: +1 je connais aussi cet usage de « sortir avec quelqu'un ».